# How to maintain states of radio button and checkbox using jquery (no page refresh required)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have one `<select>` with three options called `select`,`Scheme1`,`Scheme2`. Based on selection of Scheme # I have to toggled `Checkboxes` (for Scheme 1) and `radio` buttons (for Scheme 2).

[image] [image]

Case 1: When I select `Scheme1` option and checked two (`B` and `C`) `checkboxes`, it's fine.

Case 2: When I select `Scheme2` option and checked `radio` buttons and I selects `B` option.

Now if I again select `Scheme1` I lost my previous selection of two check boxes A and B and if I select `Scheme2` I also had lost my selected option `B` from radio button.

How can I handle this. Currently each time I am drawing new checkbox list and radio buttons list.

How can I maintain the states for both checkboxes and radio bottons?

I have following HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<select name="sltScheme" onchange="funCall(this.value)">
    <option value="select">Select Scheme</option>
    <option value="Scheme1">Scheme 1</option>
    <option value="Scheme2">Scheme 2</option>
</select>

<!-- will be displayed when Scheme 1 is selected but will be overwritten by Radio buttons-->
<div id="schemeContainer" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
    <span id="ele_0">
        <input name="schemeType[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
    </span>
    <lable>A<br></lable>
    <span id="ele_1">
        <input name="schemeType[]" type="checkbox" value="2">
    </span>
    <lable>B<br></lable>
    <span id="ele_2">
        <input name="schemeType[]" type="checkbox" value="3">
    </span>
    <lable>C<br></lable>
</div>

<!--This separate DIV is just for illustration purpose only. Actually Radio buttons will be overwritten by Checkboxes and vice versa-->

<!-- will be displayed when Scheme 2 is selected but will be overwritten by Checkboxes-->
<div id="schemeContainer" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
    <span id="ele_0">
        <input name="schemeType[]" type="radio" value="1">
    </span>
    <lable>A<br></lable>
    <span id="ele_1">
        <input name="schemeType[]" type="radio" value="2">
    </span>
    <lable>B<br></lable>
    <span id="ele_2">
        <input name="schemeType[]" type="radio" value="3">
    </span>
    <lable>C<br></lable>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And I have following JavaScript/jQuery Code (note that I have added jQuery library so don't confuse with HTML code)

```
<script>
    function funCall(schemeType)
    {
        var obj = jQuery("input[name='schemeType[]']");
        if(schemeType == "scheme1")
        {
            for(i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
            {
                var eleval = obj[i].value;
                jQuery("#ele_"+i).each(function(i) {
                    jQuery(this).html('<input value = "'+eleval+'" type="checkbox" name="'+obj[i].name+'" id="'+obj[i].id+'"/>');
                });
                obj[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
        else if(schemeType == "scheme2")
        {
            for(i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
            {
                jQuery("#ele_"+i).each(function(i) {
                    jQuery(this).html('<input value = "'+eleval+'"  type="radio" name="'+obj[i].name+'" id="'+obj[i].id+'"/>');
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Edit:

I have removed `id` attribute from both checkboxes and radio buttons because using `name` attribute.

**Edit 2:**

I have here shown 2 divs with same id `<div id="schemeContainer"` just for ILLUSTRATION PURPOSE ONLY. Actually there should only be one DIV and not TWO. I will be replacing radio and checkboxes in that single div only.

Comment: First of all, each of your inputs should have a unique id attribute, and each of the two sets (checkbox / radio) should have a unique name.

Comment: @StevenMoseley, Thanks for pointing. Please see updated code. I am using `name` attribute so no need for `id` attribute for me. And as I am using `[]` in `name` attribute as an `Array`

Comment: The same goes for the `div`s (`id="schemeContainer"`): the id should be unique, and using the same id twice on a page is very naughty.

Comment: @NielsAbildgaard, I have mentioned in HTML comment that it is just for illustration (2 divs with same id) purpose only. Actually it should be one div only with Unique ID.

Comment: Ah, right, my bad. I didn't see that comment until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change some code here:

1). Change div id (group of radio button container)

```
<div id="schemeContainer1" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
    .......
</div>
```

2). Change div id (group of check box button container)

```
<div id="schemeContainer2" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
   .....
</div>
```

3). Change JavaScript to show hide radio or check box container based on section.

```
function funCall(schemeType)
{
    if(schemeType == "Scheme1")
    {
        jQuery("#schemeContainer1").show();
        jQuery("#schemeContainer2").hide();
    }
    else if(schemeType == "Scheme2")
    {
        jQuery("#schemeContainer1").hide();
        jQuery("#schemeContainer2").show();
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery("#schemeContainer2").show();
        jQuery("#schemeContainer1").show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I cannot keep two separate DIVs as I have mentioned in HTML comment.

Comment: I was thinking what you have suggested. But have some tricky HTML structure that's why I am thinking to replace RADIO and CHECKBOXES in same div. But let me check if I could handle what you suggested in my current structure.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your html comments correctly, the issue isn't that you can't have two divs, it's that you don't want both div's to be submitted when the form is finally sent.  I would consider Raskesh's solution (using toggle to show and hide the already selected options) but add a disable for the form elements being hidden and enable when visible so that on submit the disabled fieldset is not processed by the server.

Also, if you are comfortable with an HTML5 only solution, [`fieldset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) can now take a `disabled` attribute that disables all decensdent form controls inside of it, removing the need to loop through your checkboxes to disable each one.

Here is a way to make the code lighter for jquery as well: wrap all of your swappable form fields in fieldsets with a shared class (like "swappable") and set those to show/hide. Then have a function listens for when a fieldset is made visible/hidden and a) sets the fieldset to disabled (when hidden) or not disabled (when visible) for HTML5 browsers and also has a selector for all form field types descendent of fieldsets that are hidden and have the swappable class and sets/unsets the disabled attribute for the specific fields as well. By using a class for all swappable wrappers, you not only make it easier to select the fields, you avoid accidentally disabling fields that are intentionally hidden. If you incorporate modernizr, you can skip the per-field disable if fieldset accepts disabled attribute.

Comment: Yes. You read the question correctly about HTML DIVs. I have to keep same name for both RADIO buttons and CHECKBOXES. If I go for two different DIVs at a same time then I have to change name for both RADIO and CHECKBOX.

Comment: No I am not using HTML5 and that was my question that is `DISABLE` supported below HTML5? I have little bit tricky structure to handle this situation which is already generated from previous code.

Comment: It is worth testing if two controls have the same name and one is set to disabled if the other is passed in (and what would happen if both are passed in not-disabled just so you know the worst-case scenario). I believe name attribute is not required to be unique, and disabled is carried by the control, not the attribute, so it should be fine.

Comment: @NullVoid disable is supported at the form-control (radio, checkbox) since always, it's just not as clean as applying it to parent fieldset (so you have to apply disabled to each non-visible form control ie each checkbox).

Comment: Yes. That's what I have to do when form is submitted but the main problem is to show/hide controls and maintaining their states.

Comment: So when you hide the control, you also set the disabled attribute, when you show it, you unset the disabled attribute.  Is that what you're asking how to do, or if it's possible? You can use two divs with controls having the same name and the server will only see the name/value pairs that are not disabled on submit. so sharing names is fine.

Comment: Ok. Let me check with suggested. My main problem is that I cannot create two different DIVs as per current structure and code. But let me verify if I can make it happened.